# How can I implement search into my action bar?

Tags: java, android, search, android-actionbar

My basic android app displays a list of all the installed apps on my phone. I've looked on google for tutorials on how to do this but they're quite confusing. I want to add a feature to my action bar like Google has for their apps so I can search down the list for an app

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        setTitle("Apps");
        getActionBar();
        loadApps();
        loadListView();
        addClickListener();

    }

    private PackageManager manager;
    private List<AppDetail> apps;
    private void loadApps(){
        manager = getPackageManager();
        apps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo ri:availableActivities){
            AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
            app.label = ri.loadLabel(manager);
            app.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
            apps.add(app);
        }
    }

    private ListView list;
    private void loadListView(){
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.apps_list);

        ArrayAdapter<AppDetail> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AppDetail>(this,
                R.layout.list_item,
                apps) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(convertView == null){
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }

                ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
                appIcon.setImageDrawable(apps.get(position).icon);

                TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_label);
                appLabel.setText(apps.get(position).label);



                return convertView;
            }
        };

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void addClickListener(){
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                                    long id) {
                Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps.get(pos).name.toString());
                HomeActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully followed this guide before. It shows you how to set up the search interface.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html